# Select all in the Contextual Action Bar?

Tags: android, select, android-actionbar

The contextual action bar for android 4.0 doesn't seem to have a built in select all. More annoyingly, it seems to have no way to access or set the 'checked' property for the views it manages.

Is there a way to get set all the views it considers to 'checked' or a built in 'select all' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The contextual action bar for android 4.0 doesn't seem to have a built in select all

That is because the contextual action bar is not tied to a single concept of selection.

> More annoyingly, it seems to have no way to access or set the 'checked' property for the views it manages.

Why would it? There is no "checked" property on an `EditText`. Yet, a contextual action bar is used for contextual operations on selected text.

> Is there a way to get set all the views it considers to 'checked' or a built in 'select all' ?

You are welcome to do so on whatever widget contains the things to be selected. "Select all" on an `EditText` is vastly different than "select all" in a `ListView`, for example. Since the `ActionMode` knows nothing about what has triggered the `ActionMode`, you have to handle that yourself.